# Azure Devops custom extension and current release context

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

With Azure Devops Services, I need to get azure devops user id which triggered a release, from task.json.

I've got a datasourcebinding with Azure API Management service. This has to get Azure API Management tag based on user id. I've tried different approach :

```
  {
    "target": "TEST",
    "endpointId": "$(ConnectedServiceName)",
    "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}/subscriptions/{{endpoint.subscriptionId}}/resourceGroups/$(ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/$(APIM)/products?tags=**$(Release.RequestedForId)**&api-version=2019-12-01",
    "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*]",
    "resultTemplate": "{\"Value\" : \"{{{id}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{properties.displayName}}}\" }"
  },
```

I tried also with {{Release.RequestedForId}} but it didn't work.

I saw different resources for datasourcebinding support :

tfs:teamfoundation – Any micro service hosted within TFS (e.g. Build, Test etc.)
tfs:packaging – Packaging service
tfs:feed – Feed service
tfs:rm – Release Management service
tfs:governance - Governance service
tfs:ems - Extension Management service

I found examples for tfs:feed and tfs:teamfoundation only.

Is there any section for users ? Is there any additional information apart from Azure Devops Services REST API ?

Quite few examples in but none for user request.

Is it possible to get current context release variables or azure devops user id directly in task.json ?

This would be a huge help.

Thank you !

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

You made a small misatke. Instead of `Release.RequestedForId` please give a try for `Release.Deployment.RequestedFor` of `Release.Deployment.RequestedForId`

Docs for `Release.Deployment.RequestedFor` says:

> The display name of the identity that triggered (started) the
>   deployment currently in progress. Not available in TFS 2015.
>
> Example: Mateo Escobedo

Docs for `Release.Deployment.RequestedForId` says:

> The ID of the identity that triggered (started) the deployment
>   currently in progress. Not available in TFS 2015.
>
> Example: 2f435d07-769f-4e46-849d-10d1ab9ba6ab

You have this written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch).